# Magento 2: Move add to cart in Your Customisation (bundle product page) before Go back to product details

Tags: magento2, bundle

I want to customize the bundle product page on the magento2 store.
How to move the "add to cart" button to before "Go back before link", Also I want to validate fixed quantity too. So I can hide the "Customize and Add to Cart" button.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

[image: budle page]

Comment: Check my answer, https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/304336/59677

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the below code in

> app/design/frontend/[Vendor_Theme]/[Theme]/Magento_Bundle/layout/catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="product.info.addtocart.bundle" destination="product.info.bundle.options.top" before="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Clear the cache and check.

Comment: Thanks Kishor, but the image gallery doesn't show. When I revert code it show again.

Comment: If you already have the catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml in your theme, Then just add the <move element="product.info.addtocart.bundle" destination="product.info.bundle.options.top" before="-"/> in <body> tag, Don't replace whole file code.

Comment: Is it worked for you?