# Magento 2.3.4: Want to change the location of bundle product options near add to cart

Tags: magento2, bundled-product, magento2.3.4, product-page, listing

I want these two portions of the listing in the same box under the (Choose Your Items) Button.
I have tried to do with the XML but it changes the configurable list and simple product.

[image: Bundle Product]

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/304336/85907

Comment: It's just change the addtocart btn above the options, but i want options and add to cart button at the same place Under the short description